# Call a $scope function on date change in UI Bootstrap's Datepicker not using $watch

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is it possible to call a function after a click on a date or month in datepicker without using $watch? Currently, I'm using $watch to monitor changes in date to trigger a task.

If so, can you please show how the template should call the $scope function?

Comment: `ng-change` should work.

Comment: It worked! I'll now be able to get rid of $watch :)

Answer (score 0):

Taking forward Anthony suggestion.

```
<p class="input-group" style="padding-top:5px;">
    <input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" style="width:165px; height:34px;" ng-change="changefun();" class="form-control" ng-model="myDate" is-open="isOpened" " datepicker-options="Options" calendarWeeks="false" close-text="Close" required/>
    <span class="input-group-btn" style="float:left">
      <button style="height:34px; padding-right:0;" type="button" ng-click="Open()" class="btn btn-default">
        <img border="0" src="/_layouts/15/images/calendar_25.gif?rev=23" />
      </button>
    </span>
</p>
```

Refer [link](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for more detail